# Creating a sysfs attribute group and the corresponding device in dev/

Tags: sysfs

I am creating a Linux device driver for a PCIe card.
I've run into a problem when creating the corresponding sysfs entry. At first, I had created an attribute group with the needed

```
DEVICE_ATTR(...)
struct attribute *...
struct attribute_group ...
```

and so on, and then I've added the store() and show() functions.
Everything worked brilliantly, and the requested class was created in

> /sys/bus/pci/drivers//module/drivers/pci:/0000:01:00.0

/
The problem was that no entry was automatically created in /dev/ !!

I've spent several hours looking on the net, and the only solution I've found was to use:

```
class_create() and then
device_create()
```

but this creates another entry in /sysfs/devices/virtual/..., which is IMHO ugly and totally unnecessary.

What I would like is to have my set of attributes AND the corresponding entry in /dev/

How can I achieve that? Even a pointer to an example that does this would be extremely helpful (I've looked for one for hours, without any luck :( )

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Rob

**Answer:** I made a stupid mistake in choosing the class of the driver. Properly setting up a pci driver solved this.

Comment: Did you register your pci device?

Comment: With a pci_register_driver() you mean? Yes in the init()

Comment: Then in probe function also may be you have enable device. If possible then can you put log or simple driver code you have followed?

Comment: @RH6..Make sure that you have register device. _Example_.. if your device type is character device then you should use **register_chrdev()** like function to register your device..

Comment: The very first thing I do in init is a alloc_chrdev_region(). In the probe, I have a pci_enable_device() on the pci_dev that is given as a parameter to the probe(). (P.S.: Thanks for your answers!)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this :

http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/

In your case follow the bus driver example.

Comment: I've solved the issue -- my short term memory prevents me from remembering how :S, but I've solved it! Thanks anyway for your answer!